# Iframe Id null in iframe onload method

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, iframe, blob.topdf

I am loading iframe dynamically on button click of the window, the iframe uses pdfJs library.

However, in onload method of the iframe, I am geting iframe object as null, and getting error.

This is my code, can you please help. I am getting error as cannot read property contentWindow of Null.

This is my code:

```
<template if:false={showInput}>
    <iframe id="pdfFramePopup" height="500px" width="1050px" src="/resource/lcins1_pdfjs/web/viewer.html" onload={loadPdfModal} class="pdfFrame"></iframe>
</template>
```

JS Code

```
  loadPdfModal() {
    console.log('document.getElementById(pdfFramePopup)--->'+document.getElementById('pdfFramePopup'));
    console.log('Inside pdf viewer -- iframe onload');

    try {
        var pdfData = this.pdfBlob;
        console.log('document.getElementById(pdfFramePopup)--->'+document.getElementById('pdfFramePopup'));
        pdfData = pdfData.trim();
        console.log('pdfData-->' + pdfData);
        if (typeof pdfData != 'undefined') {
            document.getElementById('pdfFramePopup').contentWindow.postMessage(pdfData, '*');
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Error: ' + e.message);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the template selector and not the `document.getElementById` function to query the IFrame.
Also the `id` attribute is auto calculated by the LWC framework, and its is not recommended to use the it, its overwritten even if you provide the custom. Use the class selector instead.

As you already have assigned the class to the IFrame, you can query that like this.

```
this.template.querySelector(".pdfFrame").contentWindow.postMessage("sdsdsd", '*');
```